# How can I find the missing sequence in column? sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get only the missing sequence of consecutives numbers ( Days of week ), ( I have found solutions using `with` but in my case I don't like to use it )

Is there any solution to find the missing sequence from a column contains consecutive numbers from 1 to 7.

**As an example:**

```
DayId

  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
```

The expected result should display:

```
MissingDays

  6
  7
```

**Another example:**

```
DayId

  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  7
```

The expected result should display:

```
MissingDays

  6
```

This query will return the correct result if the missing number is only one number not a sequence because I have used `top 1` , how can I return the missing sequence ?

```
SELECT top 1 dayId + 1 available_id
  FROM days t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT * 
    FROM days
   WHERE dayId = t.dayId+1
)
 ORDER BY dayId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a list of days.  You can define this manually and use `left join`:

```
select v.dayid
from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7)
     ) v(dayid) left join
     days d
     on d.dayid = v.dayid
where d.dayid is null;
```

Comment: What's `v`? because I got an error when executing this query

Comment: `v` is the table alias on the values clause.